# Whats the difference between THsHaServer and TNonblockingServer?

Tags: thrift, thrift-protocol

Whats the difference between those two ?
And where do I find a good doc about what is what ?
I went through their JavaDoc, and it doesn't explain a lot of questions [ which I am going to haunt you guys with :) ]

Answer (score 1):

The best I could find is from the Thrift Wiki - [ThriftUsageC++](http://wiki.apache.org/thrift/ThriftUsageC++):

> TNonblockingServer with a thread pool
>   is the c++ alternative of the JAVA
>   THsHaServer, TNonblockingServer
>   without a thread pool is the c++
>   alternative of the JAVA
>   TNonblockingServer.